# Unable to get missingFiles.txt to add values

Tags: regex, vb.net

I've been working on this for awhile and have gotten lots of help (Thank you!). I believe I'm on the last step of my code. I need to write to a MissingFiles.txt file, I've added it in my Else clause but it never fires. Even when I know there are missing graphics. It does copy the files found in a try/catch. I was thinking maybe add the missingText file code in the catch part but that didn't do anything.
So I'm back to using the Else clause in my If System.IO.File.exists else part.

```
    Private Sub btnMoveGraphics(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim imgLocation = txtSearchICN.Text
    Dim MissingFiles = MoveLocation & "\Reports\MissingGraphicList.txt"
    Dim fileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(imgLocation).Join(
        GraphicList,
        Function(p) Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p),
        Function(f) f,
        Function(p, f) p)

    ' create the directory first (does nothing if it already exists)
    Dim MoveImgTo = MovePath & "\Figures"
    Directory.CreateDirectory(MoveImgTo)

    ' copy each file
    For Each fileName In fileNames
        Dim copyFilesTo = Path.Combine(MoveImgTo, Path.GetFileName(fileName))
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then
            'The file exists

            Debug.Write(vbCr & "ICN file name - " & fileName)
            Try
                System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(MoveImgTo, Path.GetFileName(fileName)))
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Else
            Debug.Write(vbCr & "Missing file name - " & fileName)
            'the file doesn't exist
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(MissingFiles, IO.FileMode.Append)
            objWriter.WriteLine(fileName)
            objWriter.Close()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I remember your previous questions. Do you still want to determine image names from `GraphicList` that are missing from `imgLocation`?

Comment: @RobertBaron yes that's exactly what I want to do. I thought it would catch on the Else code, but it just runs right through and gives no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible solutions to your question. They all involve two steps, (1) get the list of files in the `imgLocation` folder, and (2) compare that list with the `GraphicList` list.

One solution is to compare the two lists directly.

```
' Get the list of file
Dim fileNames as String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(imgLocation)

' For each name in GraphicList, we want to check whether it is in fileNames.
For Each name As String In GraphicList
    ' See whether name appears in fileNames.
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    ' Search name in fileNames.
    For Each fileName As String In fileNames
        ' GraphicList consists of filename without extension, so we compare name
        ' with the filename without its extension.
        If Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) = name Then
            ' The fileName name exists.
            ' ... do whatever code ...
            ' Set found to True so we do not process name as missing, and exit For.
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not found = True Then
        ' There is no fileName name.
        ' ... do whatever code ...
    End If
Next
```

If the number of files you have are in the hundreds, then this solution will be efficient enough. However, if you have many more files, in the thousands or more, then there are more efficient solutions that involves using data structures such as dictionaries and sets.

Final note, instead of:

```
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(MissingFiles, IO.FileMode.Append)
objWriter.WriteLine(fileName) ' <== Here it should be a name from GraphicFile because filename does not exist.
objWriter.Close()
```

You could simply write:

```
File.AppendAllText(MissingFiles, name & vbNewLine)
```

Comment: How would I copy the files without the files extensions?

Comment: @Maxine Hammett - The variable `filename` is the actual file name, full path with extension.

Comment: You are so awesome! Thank you

Comment: I'm getting a path error. Here I dim the path Dim MoveImgTo = MovePath & "\Figures\" then I use it System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, MoveImgTo & "\" & fileName) the error i'm getting is 'The given paths format is not supported

Comment: @Maxine Hammett - You have an extra \, try `System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, MoveImgTo & fileName)`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I even get the error if I give it a hard path C:\Test\24 Delivery App\TestSub\Figures

Comment: When I looked at the output the copy files into folder has the from folder in it's results. E.g. Copying file into folder C:\Test\24 Delivery App\TestSub\FiguresC:\Test\24 Delivery App\figures\ICN-GAASIB0-00-422100-A-0YJB5-00020-A-001-01.cgm

Comment: @Maxine Hammett - filename is the full path, use `Path.GetFilename()` to extract the filename part.

Comment: I was just about to tell you that's what i did. Thank you for all this help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196878/discussion-between-maxine-hammett-and-robertbaron).